# How can I select from 2 tables and in every 5 row in the first loop, show 1 item from table 2?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a mysql db and use .asp classic.

I want to select from 2 tables, the first is products and the second one is adds. And I want to display 1add and then 5 products and then 1 add and so on, like this.

```
Add1
Product1
Product2
Product3
Product4
Product5
Add2
Product6
Product7...
```

So with this I just select from the both tables and then all the adds ar displayed at first and then all products.

```
sql = " SELECT * 
        FROM produkt,annonser 
        where produkt.publicera='true' 
            AND produkt.antal > "&nr&" 
            AND annonser.publicera='true' 
            AND annonser.antal > "&nr&" 
        order by 
            produkt.datum DESC, 
            annonser.datum DESC,
            produkt.artikel ASC, 
            annonser.artikel ASC limit 10"
set rs = conn.Execute (sql)
```

So how can I select the way I want?
Any input appreciated, thanks.

Ok, so this works.

```
For i = 1 to 10
  If i mod 5 = 1 Then
     [Get the current Add and display it]
     if not rsAdds.EOF Then
        rsAdds.MoveNext()
     End If
  End If   
  if not rsProducts.EOF Then 
  [Display the Product]
  rsProducts.MoveNext()
Next
```

But now Im trying to loop it all again, and I have tried to use rs.MoveFirst in different way, but I only get rs.eof or rs.buf is true so it is not moving the cursor to the first record and loop again?

So I would like to loop the above first and then loop it again, something like this.

```
For i = 1 to 10
      If i mod 5 = 1 Then
         [Get the current Add and display it]
         if not rsAdds.EOF Then
            rsAdds.MoveNext()
         End If
      End If   
      if not rsProducts.EOF Then 
      [Display the Product]
      rsProducts.MoveNext()
    Next

//Set the rs to move first so that the below will run-----

For x = 1 to 10
      If x mod 5 = 1 Then
         [Get the current Add and display it]
         if not rsAdds.EOF Then
            rsAdds.MoveNext()
         End If
      End If   
      if not rsProducts.EOF Then 
      [Display the Product]
      rsProducts.MoveNext()
    Next
```

So where or how do I move the rs to the first post after the first loop so it can run the second code?
Thanks.

Comment: What are your tables structures ?

Comment: You tried using `MoveFirst` and that didn't work? It may be that your recordset can only be read one-way. I believe there are properties or options you can set when you open the recordset that allow it to be read both backwards and forwards. However, I don't remember the options off-hand. I'll have to look them up, but I suggest you look at the `Execute` command, and at `Recordset` properties, to see if there's anything that looks like it might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume by `ASP classic` you mean actual VBA (or javascript?) in a file, without .NET or controls.

You're going to have to do this with a combination of procedural code and SQL. Since it looks like your Adds and your Products aren't related to each other, you probably should pull them in separate queries.

So the code would look something like this:

```
Dim rsAdds = [query and code to get the Adds]
Dim rsProducts = [query and code to get the Products]

' I'm not sure if you want just 10 products displayed, or all of them.  I'm going 
' I'm going to go with 10.

For i = 1 to 10
  If i mod 5 = 1 Then
     [Get the current Add and display it]
     if not rsAdds.EOF Then
        rsAdds.MoveNext()
     End If
  End If    
  [Display the Product]
  rsProducts.MoveNext()
Next i
```

If all you want is just to interpolate data from two unrelated tables, *without concern for what the data actually is*, don't waste time trying to trick SQL into doing it for you.  Do it procedurally.

Comment: Thanks Ann, I will test it. I want all the products and I have only 10 adds.

Comment: Thanks Ann, it works. So will this display all my products, or just the all the product s as long as For i = 1 to 10 haven't come to 10?

Comment: Just the first 10.

Comment: Ann, could you please help me a bit more? I have added a new problem to my question :-) Thanks.

Comment: @ClaesGustavsson I'll try, but I'm traveling today. You tried using `MoveFirst` and that didn't work? It may be that your recordset can only be read one-way. I believe there are properties or options you can set when you open the recordset that allow it to be read both backwards and forwards.  However, I don't remember the options off-hand.  I'll have to look them up, but I suggest you look at the `Execute` command, and at `Recordset` properties, to see if there's anything that looks like it might help.